# Freeform Pro & ExpressionEngine

Tags: solspace-freeform, spam

I'm getting a large number of spam from one of my contact forms and not sure how I can reduce this using Freeform Pro.

I've tried using the default CAPTCHA but I can't get that to work. Is there a way I can not allow HTML in the textarea element in my form?

Does anyone have any good examples or tips to help me reduce it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I bought and installed [SNAPTCHA](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/snaptcha) when I encountered that kind of issue - worked brilliantly. Easy to install and worth every penny of its really reasonable $14 price tag.

Answer (score 1):

There's a free add-in called "Freeform Anti-Spam" - which adds a honeypot field which can help cut down spam a bit. And you can have it check against blacklists to cut out spammers.

It's free. It's here: http://www.vayadesign.net/software/freeform-antispam (Devot-ee link for reviews and other stuff: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freeform-anti-spam)